# Composite another image, but with margin/padding

Tags: imagemagick

I am currently doing the following to overlay a large image onto another:

```
$ convert orig.png overlay.png -gravity center -composite new.png
```

overlay.png is large and really just a semi-transparent texture.

But in some cases I'd like to have a 1 pixel sized margin around the overlay. So:

```
+--------------+
|  +--------+  |
|  | Overlay|  |
|  +--------+  |
+--------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: it seems that you mean "border" rather than "margin" or "padding". [They are different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhiQGPtD1PQ "CSS Box Model Tutorial - Padding, Margin, and Border - YouTube")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, for example you can add a border to `overlay.png` image and then compose the result with `orig.png` image.

To add a white 1px margin you can use these commands:

```
convert overlay.png -bordercolor White -border 1x1 overlay_border.png
convert orig.png overlay_border.png -gravity center -composite new.png
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I have not been able to get off my current project to test this -- and I did a rather hackney work around -- but it looks like a solution.